# Match string, copy line to next line and modify string using sed

Tags: sed

I have a file that contains 2 lines

- Line1: " My name is ABCD".
- Line2 "My name is XYZ".

I want to copy ALL lines with string "My name" and paste the entire line on the next line but also change the  line with new string. EG: New file should look like:

- Line1: "My name is ABCD"
- Line2:"My name is ABCD and age 2"
- Line3: "My name is XYZ"
- Line4: "My name is XYZ and age 2"

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
sed 's/My name.*/&\n& and age 2/' file
```

Explanations:

- The pattern: `My name.*` search for lines containing `My name` followed by any characters `.*`
- The substitution: `&` replaces with matching string, followed by a newline `\n`, followed by the matching string again `\&`, followed by `and age 2`

To edit the file *in place*, add the `-i` flag:

```
sed -i 's/My name.*/&\n& and age 2/' file
```

Comment: Awesom! Thanks the above worked. If I need to insert "and age 2" after "is" in the string what should be the modification to the above command?

Comment: To insert after is: `sed '/My name is/p;s//& and age 2/' file`

Comment: Sorry the above didnt work. What I meant was: In my original question the copied line had appended "and age 2" after the entire original string. Now I want to string match again (with "is") for the copied line and insert "and age 2" there followed by the rest of the string as copied from the earlier line.

Comment: Please edit your question with give the desired output.

Comment: Output file should look like this:

Comment: Output file should look like this: 
    Line1: "My name is ABCD"
    Line2:"My name is and age 2 ABCD"
    Line3: "My name is XYZ"
    Line4: "My name is and age 2 XYZ"
Basically I want to match a string ("is" in the above example) in the copied version of the lines (line2 and line4 above) and only after replacing the string with the additional string ("is and age 2") want to print it on the next line.

Comment: Another approach using backreferences: `sed '/My name/p;{s/\(.*is\)\(.*\)/\1 and age 2\2/}' file`. But the output will be the same as with the command above in comment.

Comment: Awesome! Problem solved. The above worked. Thanks a million!

Comment: @Sameer , you should mark this answer as correct to close question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
1
{
  print $0, "and age 2"
}
```

Or:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
awk '1 {print $0, "and age 2"}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{Q=$0;sub(/\".$/," and age 2\".",Q);print $0 ORS Q}' Input_file
```